# DITA-OTによるhtml5変換のカスタム化について教えてください

Tags: html, xml, xsl, dita-ot

最新DITA-OT（ver.4.2）によるditaファイルの**html5変換のカスタム化**について教えてください。

以前のAntビルドファイルを使用する方法ではなく、.propertiesファイルとditaコマンドを使用して、標準仕様のxsl変換の一部を、別の変換に変更したいと思います。
以下のsample.ditaを用意して標準変換すると、**結果1**のhtlmが生成されますが、これを**結果2**のようなhtmlを生成させる方法を教えてください。

**sample.dita**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_df3_xzq_q1c">
    <title>DITA-OT TEST</title>
    <body>
        <p>Convert dita files to html using DITA-OT.</p>
        <ol>
            <li><p>Prepare an XSL file containing another transformation.</p></li>
            <li><p>Create a properties file.</p></li>
            <li><p>Use the dita command to perform conversion processing/p></li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</topic>
```

コマンドラインから以下を実行（C：直下にtest_DITA-OTフォルダを作成し、各ファイルを格納）

```
C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\bin/dita -f html5 -i C:\test_DITA-OT\sample.dita -o C:\test_DITA-OT\sample.html
```

**結果1**（生成されるhtml）

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="copyright" content="(C) Copyright 2024">
    <meta name="generator" content="DITA-OT">
    <title>DITA-OT TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonltr.css">
</head>
<body id="topic_df3_xzq_q1c">
    <main role="main">
        <article role="article" aria-labelledby="ariaid-title1">
            <h1 class="title topictitle1" id="ariaid-title1">DITA-OT TEST</h1>
            <div class="body">
                <p class="p">Convert dita files to html using DITA-OT.</p>
                <ol class="ol">
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Prepare an XSL file containing another transformation.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Create a properties file.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Use the dita command to perform conversion processing.</p>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**結果2**（希望する変換結果：ol要素をul要素にする）

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="copyright" content="(C) Copyright 2024">
    <meta name="generator" content="DITA-OT">
    <title>DITA-OT TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonltr.css">
</head>
<body id="topic_df3_xzq_q1c">
    <main role="main">
        <article role="article" aria-labelledby="ariaid-title1">
            <h1 class="title topictitle1" id="ariaid-title1">DITA-OT TEST</h1>
            <div class="body">
                <p class="p">Convert dita files to html using DITA-OT.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Prepare an XSL file containing another transformation.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Create a properties file.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li">
                        <p class="p">Use the dita command to perform conversion processing.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

dita-ot-4.2.1に付属したマニュアルでは、.propertiesファイルを作成して、ditaコマンドによる変換時に、.propertiesファイルを指定する…とあったので、以下の2ファイルを用意し、ditaのコマンドを実行しました。

**overwrite.properties**

```
args.xsl=C:/test_DITA-OT/over_write.xsl
```

**over_write.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

コマンドラインから以下を実行

```
C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\bin/dita -f html5 -i C:\test_DITA-OT\sample.dita -o C:\test_DITA-OT\sample.html --propertyfile=C:/test_DITA-OT/overwrite.properties
```

しかし、以下のエラーが表示されて変換は行われませんでした。

```
Error: Element must have an @version attribute
Error: Build failed with an exception: C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\plugins\org.dita.base\build.xml:28: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\plugins\org.dita.html5\build_dita2html5.xml:128: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\plugins\org.dita.html5\build_dita2html5.xml:160: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to compile stylesheet 'file:/C:/test_DITA-OT/over_write.xsl': Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:582)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
        at org.dita.dost.invoker.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
        at org.dita.dost.invoker.Main.startAnt(Main.java:240)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: C:\dita-ot-4.2.1\plugins\org.dita.html5\build_dita2html5.xml:128: The following error occurred while executing this line:
（以下、同様メッセージが続く）
```

基本的な考え方に誤りがあればご指摘をいただき、上記が実現できる方法をご教授いただきたいです。
.propertiesファイルを使用する方法を優先したいですが、Antビルドファイルを使用してリビルドさせる方法でも結構です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 元ファイルを書き換えておくのが正攻法に思えますが、こちらを使わないのは何か理由がありますか？

Comment: 元ファイルというのは、DITA-OTに組み込まれたXSLファイルのことでしょうか？これに触れる（書き換える）ことは一般的ではないという認識でした。また、既に特殊化が施されている場合、元ファイルの書き換えが何某に影響するのを避けるため、ピンポイントでXSLファイルの上書きをしたいと思いました。ただし、多分に知識不足なところがありますので、今回の質問が見当はずれであれば、またご指摘いただければと思います。